# Multer upload.field not store image in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, multer

I have trying many times to get the result in an arry of dB but all the time programs runs images are uploaded to the dist folder but it is not showing any array on dB.i use mvc pattern,. Hare I need to upload to image fields one for category icon and anather one for category banner

/* model file */

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
  
 const  categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
     name: String, 
     camission:String, 
     icon:Array, 
     banner:Array, 
     mtitel:String, 
     mdiscp:String 
      
      
      
 }); 
  
 module.exports = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema
```

);

/* route file */

```
const express = require("express"); 
 const category_route = express(); 
  
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
 category_route.use(bodyParser.json()); 
 category_route.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 
 const controller = require('../Controller/Category'); 
 const Multer = require('multer') 
 const Path = require('path'); 
 const multer = require("multer"); 
  
 category_route.use(express.static('public')); 
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({ 
     destination : function(req,files,cb){ 
         cb(null,Path.join(__dirname,'../public/category'),function(err,sucess){ 
             if(err){ 
                 throw err; 
             } 
         }); 
     }, 
     filename:function(req,files,cb){ 
         const name = Date.now()+'-'+ files.originalname; 
         cb(null,name, function(err, sucess){ 
             if(err){ 
                 throw err; 
             } 
         }); 
     }  
  }); 
  
  const upload = multer({storage:storage}) 
  
  
 category_route.post('/add-category',upload.fields([ 
     { 
       name: "icon", 
       maxCount: 1, 
     }, 
     { 
       name: "banner", 
       maxCount: 1, 
     } 
   ]), controller.addCategory); 
  
  
 module.exports = category_route;
```

/*controller file */

```
const Category = require("../Model/Category"); 
  
 const addCategory = async (req, res) => { 
   try { 
  
     var arrIcon = []; 
     for(let i=0; i<req.files.length; i++){ 
       arrIcon[i] = req.files[i].filename; 
     } 
     var arrBanner = []; 
     for(let j=0; j<req.files.length; j++){ 
       arrBanner[j] = req.files[j].filename; 
     } 
  
     const catData = await Category.find(); 
      
     if (catData.length > 0) { 
       let checking = false; 
       catData.every((i) => { 
         if (i.name.toLowerCase() === req.body.name.toLowerCase()) { 
           checking = true; 
           console.log("FOUND"); 
           return false; 
         } 
         console.log("NOT-FOUND"); 
         return true; 
       }); 
       if (checking === false) { 
         const data = new Category({ 
           name: req.body.name, 
           camission: req.body.camission, 
           icon: arrIcon, 
           banner: arrBanner, 
           mtitel: req.body.mtitel, 
           mdiscp: req.body.mdiscp, 
         }); 
         const result = await data.save(); 
         res.send(result); 
       } else { 
         res.send("Category is Already exieet"); 
       } 
     } else { 
       const data = new Category({ 
         name: req.body.name, 
         camission: req.body.camission, 
         icon: arrIcon, 
         banner: arrBanner, 
         mtitel: req.body.mtitel, 
         mdiscp: req.body.mdiscp, 
       }); 
       const result = await data.save(); 
       res.send(result); 
     } 
   } catch (error) { 
     console.log(error); 
     res.send("somthing Wrong"); 
   } 
 }; 
 module.exports = { addCategory };
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some projects same this, but I define my model in this way:

**icon: [{type: String}],
banner: [{type: String}]**

Everything else looks good.

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 

 const  categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
 name: String, 
 camission:String, 
 icon: [{type: String}], 
 banner: [{type: String}],
 mtitel:String, 
 mdiscp:String 
 }); 

 module.exports = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema
```

Comment: its Run but Not Store image on a Particular Array, The Files Would be Uploaded in the Directory, but the image array is not shown on the DB

could you tell me how to puss the Second one in here?

`category_route.post('/add-category',upload.array('icon'), controller.addCategory);`

Comment: OK Ahamed, I send what I did to add new element in an array property.

let icons= [];
icons.push(... categoryMode.icon);
let newIcons = ["./upload/icons/1.png","./upload/icons/1.png"] // As example
icons.push(...newIcons);

categoryMode.icon = icons;
await categoryMode.save();